# Does the AmbientData HttpModule need to be configured with preCondition="managedHandler"

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, 2013

In the sample web app for the preview webservice in Tridion 2013 the web.config file has the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
  <add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" 
       type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" />
```

while in the documentation, you are instructed to add this element with the attribute `preCondition="managedHandler"` Does this matter? Presumably it only makes a difference if you   access non-managed resources. Is one setting better than the other? Is it better to regard the installation guide or the sample as leading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think the main net effect of using `preCondition="managedHandler"` is that the module will only be executed on requests for managed resources (ASPX, ASCX, etc) and not for static resources (.gif, .css, etc).

You typically want ADF only to load on "dynamic" resources (your pages) and not on every request to any asset, but this depends on what you're doing with it. You could want to execute the ADF pipeline everytime a CSS is loaded (not that I think you *should*, but you *could*), so you have the option to define it yourself.

Why is it in the sample and not in the documentation? No clue. Developers didn't think it was important enough?

Comment: So reading between the lines, for a vanilla install, you should set this attribute, right?

Comment: Yes. If you don't know what it does or if you need it, it probably means you should use it. :)

Comment: Should this also be applied to the `PreviewContentModule` module in the `web.config` of a vanilla install too?